# Convert object and its sub-object in an array into map

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I have an array of objects like this:

```
let array = [
  {
    "A": [
      {
        "X": "abc123",
        "Y": "abc213",
        "Z": "xyz123"
      },
      {
        "X": "xyz7",
        "Y": "wqr",
        "Z": "dasd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "B": [
      {
        "X": "sadasd",
        "Y": "asdasd",
        "Z": "sadasd"
      },
      {
        "X": "ffff531",
        "Y": "asdddz",
        "Z": "xx11155"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to convert into map such that The outer key would be A/B as it is but the inner key should be the value of X pointing towards the value as the object itself.

```
 {
    "A": {
      
        "abc123":{
           "X": "abc123",
           "Y": "abc213",
           "Z": "xyz123"
        
      },
        "xyz7": {
          "X": "xyz7",
          "Y": "wqr",
          "Z": "dasd"
        
      }
    
  },
    "B": {
      
        "sadasd":{
          "X": "sadasd",
          "Y": "asdasd",
          "Z": "sadasd"
         },
      
        "ffff531":{
           "X": "ffff531",
           "Y": "asdddz",
           "Z": "xx11155"
        }
      
     }
}
```

I tried using the reduce method but I was only able to covert this to map when there are no nested objects but not with nested objects.

How can I do this ? Is this possible using `Array.prototype.reduce`  method?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you want. Do you want A or B to be the first key, and the value of X to be the second key?

Comment: Yes. The outer key would be A/B as it is but the inner key should be the value of X pointing towards the value as the object itself.

Comment: @IanNewson Let me know if anything else is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a single object and create nested object with wanted key.

```js
const
    data = [{ A: [{ X: "abc123", Y: "abc213", Z: "xyz123" }, { X: "xyz7", Y: "wqr", Z: "dasd" }] }, { B: [{ X: "sadasd", Y: "asdasd", Z: "sadasd" }, { X: "ffff531", Y: "asdddz", Z: "xx11155" }] }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(Object.assign({}, ...data))
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, Object.fromEntries(v.map(o => [o.X, o]))]));

console.log(result);
```